# How do I use the Ux.locale.Manager to populate text on my page dynamically

Tags: localization, sencha-touch-2.3

I am using sencha touch 2.3 and I am using the plug-in locale to change my page's language.

Whatever is included in the view of the page gets changed using the locale plug-in but lets say I want to alert some text depending on the language then how do i do it.

```
Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
            function(buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
```

So the above alert box I want to change the text "Application Update" & "This application has been updated etc etc"

So how do I do it using Ux.locale.Manager

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `Ux.locale.Manager` to do it dynamically, so instead I used [i18next](http://i18next.com) library.

Basically, you will load your translation like this: `i18n.t('common.back');`

Where `common.back` is a json resource.

Also check out this [post](http://tha-leang.blogspot.jp/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was able to change the text using Ux.locale.Manager.get(key) to change the text. But I learned something new from your article. Upvoted.